# How to keep gnome-keyring-daemon unlocked during whole login time?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome-keyring

I use Ubuntu 19 and keyring utility which uses gnome-keyring. When I log in into gnome session and then use keyring, it asks for password to unlock it and then after some time it locks back.

I would like to unlock keyring automatically when I log in, so no extra password to unlock keyring is necessary and then keep it unlocked, the same way it is on Mac OS. The keyring would only get locked when PC is rebooted or turned off or user is logged off. Mac OS has GUI for such things, did not find it in Ubuntu. Seahorse is no help. Thanks for answer

The actual command is:
sudo vmrun -vp $(keyring get vmrun osx) pause '/VirtualMachine.vmx'

The vmrun needs to be ran as sudo, but then keyring also asks for password from root and asks to unlock the key. I would like to run keyring as normal logged-in user, but su and sudo combinations I tried did not work.

Comment: You can change the password to empty, meaning without protection. You will then not be prompted at all, but also don't have to be logged in to view it ([link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/867/how-can-i-stop-being-prompted-to-unlock-the-default-keyring-on-boot)). Using for the keyring the same password as for login might also work.

Comment: Actually I see the problem is somewhere else. I am using keyring password in script that I run under sudo. So I have created password in keyring for root, but that is locked and I have to unlock it manually when running keyring in sudo script. I guess there is no way to unlock root's keyring automatically. Or is there?

Comment: Is the problem that you would like to `sudo` a specific command/script and you would like to avoid specifying the password while doing so?